# I am getting error during executing the function "subquery must return only one column"

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am getting error as "subquery must return only one column". Because i have more employees in each department. Tell me the solution to fix this issue

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dept_emp()
    RETURNS TEXT AS
    $$
    DECLARE
    cur_dept CURSOR FOR SELECT dept_name FROM dept;
    cur_emp CURSOR FOR SELECT employee_id,dob,department FROM emp;
    d RECORD;
    e RECORD;
    BEGIN
    FOR d IN SELECT dept_name FROM dept
    LOOP
        FOR e IN SELECT employee_id,dob,department FROM emp
            LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE 'Department: %',d.dept_name;
                RETURN (SELECT employee_id,dob FROM emp WHERE d.dept_name=e.department); 
            END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Your function return only one value of type text. But in your return clause you try to return 'employee_id,dob' which is obviously not a simple text value.

Comment: In my dept table i'm having 10 departments. In emp table am having 30 records(3 records for each department). Thats Y it returns 'more than one row returned'.

Comment: My Output should looks like this

Comment: I need a output like this

Department : Sales
 1.employee_id, dob
 2.employee_id, dob
 3.employee_id, dob
Department : Marketing
 1.employee_id, dob
 2.employee_id, dob
 3.employee_id, dob

Comment: Why don't you just join all those tables in a simple SQL statement? Nested FOR loops or even a function seems completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Ok i can make use of join over here. Then what will be the return type of function?

Comment: I should complete this by using nested for loop i had other tasks also